# How to update specific child value within a document in cosmos db using c#?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a document in cosmos db that needs to be updated similar to the below doc

```
{
    "userId": "1234",
    "values": {
        "A": {
            "description": "first description",
            "timestamp": "2018-10-01T12:13:09.000Z",
            "value": 5000,
            "valueWithUnit": "202 W"
        },
        "B": {
            "description": "second description",
            "timestamp": "2018-10-01T12:13:09.000Z",
            "value": 2,
            "valueWithUnit": "2.00 %"
        }
     },
    "id": "1",
    "lastUpdate": "2018-09-20T14:39:00Z",
    "_rid":  "rid",
    "_self": "self",
    "_etag": "etag",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1234
}
```

I need to update the value within 'B' from 2 to 3.

Below is the code I have so far..

```
public DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName);

Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
            .Where(r => r.Id == "1")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .SingleOrDefault();

Document doc1 = doc.GetPropertyValue<Document>("values");

Document doc2 = doc1.GetPropertyValue<Document>("B");

doc2.SetPropertyValue("value", 3);
```

How do I now update the document to reflect the new property values in cosmosdb?

Any help will be hugely appreciated

Comment: Can you add the class Document in the post?

Comment: You just need to upsert the document after you've made the changes you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. If you don't want to do any specific object mapping and you just wanna work with json then your code should look like this:

```
public DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName);

Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
            .Where(r => r.Id == "1")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .SingleOrDefault();

var docValues = doc.GetPropertyValue<dynamic>("values");
docValues.B.value = 3;
doc.SetPropertyValue("values", docValues);

await documentClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

If you used the `Document` object with the `GetPropertyValue` method you would also add all the document metadata which is not what you wanna do.

Keep in mind that if your collection is partition then you also need to provide the partition key by replacing like this:

```
await documentClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc, new RequestOptions{PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionKeyValueHere")});
```

You can also use UpsertDocumentAsync which will insert if the document doesn't exist and update if it does exist.

```
var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, "1");
await documentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(documentLink, doc);
```

And if the collection is partitioned:

```
var documentLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, "1");
await documentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(documentLink, doc, new RequestOptions{PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionKeyValueHere")});
```

You can also speed up your querying logic by turning it into a direct read.

You can simply get the document using it's id by doing this:

```
var docUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, "1");
Document doc = await productStore.CosmonautClient.DocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsync(docUri);
```

If your collection is partitioned you will need the `RequestOptions` object with the partition key value as your partition key for this document.

This is both faster and cheaper.

Comment: If you're looking for a single item by id, and you're reading the whole body, you can just use ReadDocumentAsync instead of using the Query. Read uses less RUs than query.

Comment: This falls under the "Of course there are cleaner and more performant ways to do the querying but it is not what you're asking so I will stick to the updating for now." part of the answer. I did not add it because it's not what the question is about.

Comment: Fair enough. Just thought I'd suggest it since I see that issue a lot when I'm helping folks optimize their workloads.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I ended up adding it. It's good to point users to the right direction even if it's not directly related to the question.

Comment: Oh man, I just realized that you were just copying the original OP's code. My bad, dude. Thanks for adding the suggestion anyway.